# how to use TypeScript in my npm library and make it usable in both Angular AND nodejs environment

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, package

I would like to write in TypeScript a npm package and I want that the user will be able to use it in both Angular and node environments.

I saw that this question was asked many times, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117403/creating-npm-package-for-both-browser-and-node) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748249/creating-a-typescript-library-that-can-be-used-in-browser-and-nodejs), but it's not exactly what I want. I found a lot of other responses, like this [excellent article](https://www.intricatecloud.io/2020/02/creating-a-simple-npm-library-to-use-in-and-out-of-the-browser/), but I still have a problem, and I don't know why. I try to solve it since two days and I think that I will soon become crazy.

**Example :**

My awesome package :

`index.ts`

```
import { hello } from './file-to-import';

export function sayHello() {
    hello();
}
```

`file-to-import.ts`

```
export function hello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": true,
        // ....
    }
}
```

Now I compile the library with `tsc`, publish it and try to use it in Angular for the frontend and in NodeJs for the backend.

- **First try with the combination `commonjs/es5` :**

All is ok for the backend, but in the frontend, Angular gives a warning : `... depends on 'my-awesome-module'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.`. I could ask the user to solve this problem by adding my module to `allowedCommonJsDependencies` option in `angular.json`, but I think that's not a good idea.

- **Second try with the combination `es6/es5` or `esnext/es5`:**

Now, all is ok for Angular, but nodejs says in the backend : `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

- **Third try with the combination `umd/es5`:**

All is perfect for NodeJs, but Angular throws the same error than in the first try and adds other warnings : `Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`.

I think that it's possible to transpile the module two times, one with a `tsconfig` with `esnext/es5` and the other with `commonjs/es5`, but I don't know how to do that and if it's a good idea.

Any help will be welcome !